# tf.image.stateless_random_crop VS. tf.image.random_crop. Shouldn't these be the same thing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

In tf 2.5, there are two functions for cropping an image: `tf.image.stateless_random_crop`, and `tf.image.random_crop`. The documentation states that `stateless_random_crop` is deterministic (always returns the same crop given one seed). However, `random_crop` has a seed parameter and is also deterministic, one would think. What is the actual difference between these two functions? I cannot find information about statelessness in Tensorflow anywhere.

The differences between `tf.image.stateless_random_crop`, and `tf.image.random_crop` are one line where stateless_random_uniform is used instead of a random_uniform:
stateless_random_crop: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py#L415-L465
random_crop: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py#L360-L412

I always thought that `random_crop` would always return the same crop given a seed, but it looks like maybe that wasn't always true? Any enlightenment about statelessness in Tensorflow is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random_crop` always return the same sequence of crops only when **both** global seed **and** operation seed are set.

1. global seed is set using `tf.random.set_seed(global_seed)`
2. operation seed is set by passing the seed argument into the operation, i.e., `tf.image.random_crop(value, size, seed=ops_seed)`

whereas what `stateless_random_crop` returns is totally determined by the seed you pass into it when the device and tensorflow version are unchanged.

And you are correct that the functions look redundant and duplicate but actually `tf.image.random_crop` is from the old RNGs API and it may be buggy in graph mode. The new RNGs API is `tf.random.Generator` and the stateless RNGs. For more information, see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/random_numbers

Using `tf.random.Generator` in combination with `stateless_random_crop`:

```
class new_RNGs_random_crop:
  def __init__(self,seed,size):
    self.rand_generator=tf.random.Generator.from_seed(seed)
    self.size=size
  def random_crop(self,x):
    return tf.image.stateless_random_crop(x,self.size,
           seed=self.rand_generator.uniform_full_int([2],dtype=tf.int32))

dummy_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.arange(2*3*3).reshape((2,3,3))).batch(1)
cropper=new_RNGs_random_crop(88883,(1,2,2))
dummy_dataset=dummy_dataset.map(cropper.random_crop)

for image in dummy_dataset:
  print(image)
```

Example outputs:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[3 4]
  [6 7]]], shape=(1, 2, 2), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 9 10]
  [12 13]]], shape=(1, 2, 2), dtype=int64)
```